# Getting a value of object for user-defined classes for while, if and for statements

Tags: c++

I am trying to get a bool value out of user defined object.
For example with float or int I can do something like

```
float a = 3.5
if (a) doSomething();
```

I want my class to look like this:

```
class Socket {
...
...
};
...
Socket T;

if (!T) cout << "Error occured";
else {
   doStuff();
}
```

Of course I can define a function that returns bool (like bool isValid();) and call it directly, but I would like to know if it is possible.

Comment: I think as long as the pointer isn't Null, it will always return true.

Comment: @user1084113: There are no pointers here. The question is about testing an *object* for validity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++11, you can safely convert your type to a boolean value:

```
explicit operator bool() const {return isValid();}
```

If your compiler doesn't support that, then you *could* write the same thing without `explicit`; however, that can be a bit dangerous because it enables implicit conversions to any numeric type. Instead, you could use a hack known as the [safe bool idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html):

```
private:
    typedef void (Socket::*safe_bool)() const;
    void safe_true() const {}
public:
    operator safe_bool() const {return isValid() ? &Socket::safe_true : 0;}
```

This returns a pointer type which can't be converted into anything except `bool`.